# Loop with Symfony and Twig

Tags: php, loops, symfony, twig

I've have two for loops. One with an array of all the data in a table and the other with an array where a foreign key is the table in the first array.

I wanted to see how many matches there are and check it but the loop doesn't do.

```
{% if comunidades %}
     {% for comunidad in comunidades %}
          {% if likes %}
               {{ likes[0].comunidad.id }}
               {{ likes[1].comunidad.id }}
               --{{ comunidad.id }}--
               {% if comunidad.id in likes|keys %}
                    OK
               {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

This prints:
`1 3 --3--` `1 3 --2--` `1 3 --1-- OK`

Thanks

Comment: This should not be done in Twig - better write a service that provides this data for you. Such a service is testable and completely decoupled from the templating language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the key of the likes array is an object. You should take only the id of the object usign the [map filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/map.html) like:

```
{% for comunidad in comunidades %}
          {% if likes %}
               {{ likes[0].comunidad.id }}
               {{ likes[1].comunidad.id }}
               --{{ comunidad.id }}--
               {% if comunidad.id in likes|map(p => p.comunidad.id)  %}
                    OK
               {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
```

the output will be:

```
    1
3
--3--
        OK
            1
3
--2--
            1
3
--1--
        OK
```

So only the first and the last element will match

See [this working fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/644lhi)

Hope this help